# Does a Firestorm kill a Fire Elemental?

Tags: firetop-mountain

If you invoke a Firestorm whenever an Fire Elemental is present, will the elemental be destroyed by that storm or does it feels comfortable about it?

And if he is destroyed, does it hit the mages on the turn he dies (i.e. Do you suffer 8 healht points if you're not protected against fire-ish spells : 3 from the elemental + 5 from the storm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rules are clear enought on this topic (i.e. I can understand them!)

> FIRE STORM: 
>   It will destroy but not be destroyed by a fire elemental.
>
> SUMMON FIRE ELEMENTAL:
>   An elemental will also be engulfed and destroyed by a storm of its own type but, in such an event, the storm is not neutralized although the elemental still does not attack in that turn.